# How to Fix 'mvn install' error in guava gwt

Tags: maven, guava

I am trying to build Guava 27.0.1 using the command mvn install.
Getting the below error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project guava-gwt: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.google.guava:guava-gwt:jar:27.0.1-jre: Could not find artifact com.google.guava:guava-tests:jar:tests:27.0.1-jre in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

What is the possible fix to overcome the issue 
Command used.
mvn install

Thanks

Error Log
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.google.guava:guava-tests:jar:tests:27.0.1-jre in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-google-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:325)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)

Comment: That's only a snipped of the logging out...there is more...please make a full log and post it here...A pom file would also be helpful..

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise ,Error Log added

Comment: What about the pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise guava-gwt pom.xml added,Any directions/suggestions towards resolution can be helpful

Comment: I don't wanted the pom of guava I wanted your own pom file...